# Basic Calculator with GUI

Tags: code-challenge, arithmetic

I recently had to add a small basic calculator to a project. I wrote a quick dirty one, but it seemed small enough to check with you people out here ;)

Just out of curiosity & an appetite to get surprised for some real hacky solutions, try and beat this one :

**CODE (JS/JQUERY):**

```
function scalcy() {
    var b="", p=parseFloat,t,i;
    return $("<div>").append("789/456*123-.0=+".split("").map(function(i){
        return $("<button/>").text(i).width(32).height(32).click(function(){
        b = (!p(i=$(this).text())? b.replace(/\D+$/,""): b) + i;        
        t.val(((!(i.match(/[.\d]/))? (b=eval(b.slice(0,-1))+i+"").slice(0,-1):
                p(b.match(/[.\d]+/g).pop()) || 0) + "").slice(0,8));
    })})).prepend(t=$("<input/>").width(123).click(function(){
        this.value=b="0";})).width(130);
}
```

**Screenshot (in chrome):** ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XM7mD/))

[image]

**Considerations:** Better the UI & lesser the bugs, the better.

**Minimum Functionalities:**

- Supports floating point arithmetic (/*-+),
- Reset feature,
- Continuous Operation (like working on with the last result)

**Note:**

- Use any language & library, but please not a library call like *new
  calculator()*.
- Forking the above code itself is most welcome.

---

**Additional Notes:**

- A graphical UI is obviously considered better than not having any at all.
- I'd suggest to have a look at this challenge (for inspiration): [Create a GUI Piano](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/create-a-gui-piano).

Comment: What is the objective winning criteria? How do you measure how great a UI is?

Comment: Basically the calculator should look like the calculator we all know, some buttons & a textbox (like the image above). No sacrifices to be made on that..

Comment: I don't like to duplicate UI things (and support only the new one). I have thoose buttons on my keyboard, which don't work on your solution.

Comment: well you see, most of the above code is after the GUI part. It's equivalent to me capturing the keyboard & passing it to the eval (in your case expr).

Comment: Well you see, it is not on the list of minimal functionalities.

Comment: there you go, added.

Comment: Congratulations, you just made a chamelion question that invalidated a previously valid answer.

Comment: Well I thought adding that would have given undue advantages to languages with no possibilities. Either ways, you win if no one else does, which seems more likely :)

Comment: @loxxy Maybe *no one else* attempts a question which is not well-specified and has no objective winning criterion. Reading and following the comments usually generates better questions and also more interest in solving them.

Comment: This snippet on the link provided does not work on Safari 5.1.9 (Snow Leopard 10.6.8) .

Comment: @JohannesKuhn There you go. Nothing invalidates your answer now. My bad for the edit earlier, sorry.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/OMGWTF-Finalist-01-The-Buggy-4Function-Calculator.aspx) here, and quietly slip out the door...

Comment: This is off-topic. It should be in the Code Review section of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Tcl/Tk, 100

```
pack [entry .e -textv e] -f both -e 1
bind . <Return> {catch {expr $e} e}
bind . <Escape> {set e {}}
```

Buttons are not required, so leave them alone.
The GUI is great. So simple that you can finally focus on the task that you try to do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language, so I need to ask: This isn't using a text-based interface, as opposed to graphical one?

Comment: Tk is a graphical toolkit. Yes, it has a window and so on. Just no buttons :P

Comment: Upvoted for strict interpretation of rules... one of my favorite games on this site.

Comment: I am not familiar with the language as well, but I see it is very much possible to write a gui based calcy, but would require more code, though: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1270

Comment: Tried here and works fine :)

Comment: [Failed outgolf: 118](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsIwFAXQ3a@4hKwR3KWbP@CqHdLnlUpqDOmrVEK@PVVcz3BUptaSl4ALo@YP9oRTrvoGe7g7hpeOcMRhNz19QsCZuuR4xWkWnwhBMeJVRpSZCn6fNWVY9tXA/KlUU1GGR7z9@qMNHazU1jY)

Comment: You only save 12 characters (`bind <>`) for in exchange for the lmap and list formating. Yes, this trade of isn't worth it most of the time.

Comment: [Outgolfed: 106](https://tio.run/##PcuxCoMwFAXQvV9xh64R3MXNH3AVh/i8xVKJIT5FCfn26FL3c1TmnL2VHzo6DScKwigP3cEe5oNh0QmGKF/D140oULXULbgaUazKhLhSwbsfPuDNPqVHNqtYz/pPYko5Xw)

Comment: Nice work. Yeah. I should bind to the toplevel instead. Saves a few chars.

Comment: Also tried to do sthg like https://tio.run/##BcGxDsIgFAXQ3a@4Iaw0cTdu/oArMtDnNTVUJPRpagjfjueorGOUKAmeWesPE@GUu37BAPfA/NYFjjge1lcsSLhSPzXfcNkkFkLQjOdeKiyDgWnddLT5me@YcLLpDC9RZYHfqCCshNDH@AM but it caused memory over-allocation. There are syntax subtle details on tcl I still fail to grasp!

Comment: I got an other idea. `catch` takes an additional parameter, and sets the result to this. Saves a few chars.